# Recommend a CMS and extension to build an Event Manager

Tags: cms, looking-for-a-script, lamp

I have a lead to build an event manager solution in LAMP with following functionality:

It should handle events by country, city, locality in city, type of event, venue type etc.

following are a few user features:

- to see details of city, venue, event, performer etc.
- to purchase tickets and reserve
  tables.
- to search for events by city, venue,
  type, performer etc.
- to manage favorite venues and
  performers, save events etc.
- the venues should be able to add
  their events

I plan to use a CMS (Joomla, Drupal etc.) with some ready made extension that provides most of the functionality or provide framework to build upon.

Could you guys suggest me a CMS and an extension to build this.

Comment: @Haris: Off topic on SO?

Comment: @Gens, why off topic? I think SO is for anything related to programming and development.

Comment: @Haris: Your question should be on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Haris: programmers.stackexchange.com is the Q & A place for expert programmers interested in professional discussions on software development

Comment: My friend this can be done equally well in Joomla & Drupal. So don't ask for CMS. You can ask for suitable extension in any CMS.

Comment: @John I know it is possible both in Joomla and Drupal. My point was that is there any extension which is closest to my requirements whether in Joomla or Drupal, as a matter of fact, in any other CMS.

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM will help you with that although you will not be able to book seats by number.

http://civicrm.org/try

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest having a look at a CMS like [MoST](http://www.getmost.info), which is developed specifically for event management.
These CMS's have been developed specifically for the kind of requiremetns you are talking about, so there's no need to reinvent the wheel, or mess around with plug-in compatibility issues.
They do come at a price, but the savings in time, reputation, and reliability outweigh the financial cost in my opinion.
The website for it is www.getmost.info, which gives a good overview of what you can do

Comment: thanks for the link. I have briefly gone through the site and it by the looks it does not seem to be very promising. i also could not see how is it developed specifically for event management i.e. i could not find any particular emphasis.